# Sequence number in table

Tags: oracle

I know this might have been asked before but need to find out if there is a way I can identify if my table(oracle db) is using any sequence as one of its columns? I did not write the schema so I need to find out in order to do some insert queries

Comment: You can verify in your table definition if it has a default value using a sequence, or since 12c an identity column. If your definition does not show you anything there is nothing in your DB that attaches a sequence to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to try this, although unconventional, would be to run these queries to check if there are any sequence used in your `functions` , `procedures`, `packages`.

```
select * from user_source where 
         UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%NEXTVAL%';   

select * from all_source where 
         UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%NEXTVAL%';
```

Then go to the specific procedure, function to check which column/table  gets populated by a sequence. 
Try this also with `'%CURRVAL%'`

This might not help if you are running inserts from `JDBC` or other external applications using a seqeunce.

Answer (score 0):

Always, always, state your Oracle db **version** (full number as reported by `select * from v$version`).

In Oracle 12, you can query `user_tab_columns` like so:

```
select column_name
from   user_tab_columns
where  table_name = 'EMP' and identity_column = 'YES'
```

(if you want to do this for ALL your tables at once, remove the `table_name = ...` condition from the `WHERE` clause, and instead add `table_name` to the `SELECT` clause)

Comment: hi, I am using 12 c. Thanks for your response but running above query did not yield any results. Is there any other way I can determine?

Comment: @Sara "No results" means there are no identity columns in your tables. What, you don't believe the results? Why not?

Comment: Ok. No, its not like that. One thing: does having 'identity column' mean that it has one column as a sequence?(as stated in my original problem statement)?