# Sequence associated with an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-administration

I would like to know if there is a way to find out which sequences are associated with a given Oracle table.

Comment: There is no fixed association. You are free to use any sequence anywhere you like.

Comment: In 12c, Oracle now supports IDENTITY columns. A sequence is generated with the format ISEQ$$_<object ID>

Comment: I wondered that, but the question is tagged `oracle11g`. Worth mentioning though, as it might help someone else.

Comment: You can refer my answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026110/sequence-number-in-table/47028448#47028448

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in general, short of searching the source code or `v$sql` or finding common dependencies in `all_dependencies`, because sequences created with `create sequence` are independent objects that you can use however you like.

From Oracle 12.1, if you define an [identity column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) this will generate a system-defined sequence with a name like `ISEQ$$_1744544`. You can find these in [`all_tab_identity_cols`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2791B728-3670-4960-BEEE-EA750981C0DF.htm) together with the table and column they were created for.